# How to push an image from a container to a registry in a sibling container

Tags: docker, dns, docker-registry

I'm trying to push an image from inside of one container to a registry in a sibling container, sharing the same overlay network.

Example of what I have tried:

```
erik@work ~ $ docker run --network mmmmm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu:latest sh -c "apt-get update ; apt-get install docker.io -y ; bash"
```

...

```
root@01574361ba59:/#
root@01574361ba59:/# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
01574361ba59        ubuntu:latest       "sh -c 'apt-get upda…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes                            nervous_banach
9f7019fca0a6        registry:2.6.2      "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes       5000/tcp            foobar.xxx.yy
root@01574361ba59:/# 
root@01574361ba59:/# docker tag ubuntu foobar.xxx.yy:5000/ubuntu
root@01574361ba59:/# 
root@01574361ba59:/# docker push foobar.xxx.yy:5000/ubuntu
The push refers to a repository [foobar.xxx.yy:5000/ubuntu]
Get https://foobar.xxx.yy:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup foobar.xxx.yy on 91.126.225.225:53: no such host
root@01574361ba59:/# 
root@01574361ba59:/# ping foobar.xxx.yy
PING foobar.xxx.yy (10.0.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from foobar.xxx.yy.xxx (10.0.0.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
```

Please notice the ip diff `91.126.225.225:53` <> `10.0.0.4`

Comment: That error comes from the Docker daemon on the host: you'll get the same response whether you run `docker push` from a container or directly on the host.

Comment: No, when I push it from the host it works fine, as expected... I have to specify `localhost` then though

Comment: Then you need to specify `localhost` from the container too.  You're just issuing instructions to the host's Docker daemon and it will be doing the DNS resolution.

Comment: Yes I reflected over the first part of your answer. The issue is ofc that the docker host doesn't share the same dns as the container does. Do you know how I could use the docker dns in the host?